# How to locally validate JWT using JwtDecoder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

Rule: I must use the JwtDecoder implementation. We're using different jwt validations. Mostly external. This is the first time we're doing internal JWT creation encoding and then decoding with validation.

```
    private JwtDecoder sampleDecoder(String issuerUri, String jwkUri) {
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> jwtValidator = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issueUri);
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkUri).build();
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(jwtValidator);
        return jwtDecoder;
    }
```

So previously, it was login via the external API, they give a token, then per request we validate that token using the JwtDecoder created with the JwkSetUri.

The problem I'm having now is I need to create a JwtDecoder for our internally made token. Here's how I made the token.

```
    public String createToken(String mobileNumber) throws JOSEException {
        JWTClaimsSet jwtClaimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                .issuer(securityProperties.getConciergeIssuer())
                .claim("mobileNumber", mobileNumber)
                .claim("roles", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        ECKey ecKey = new ECKeyGenerator(Curve.P_256)
                .keyID("123")
                .generate();
        JWSHeader jwsHeader = new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.ES256)
                .type(JOSEObjectType.JWT)
                .keyID(ecKey.getKeyID())
                .build();
        SignedJWT jwt = new SignedJWT(jwsHeader, jwtClaimsSet);
        jwt.sign(new ECDSASigner(ecKey.toECPrivateKey()));
        String token = jwt.serialize();
        return token;
    }
```

And as for it's `JwtDecoder` implementation, this is how I did it:

```
    private JwtDecoder customDecoder(String issuer) {
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> jwtValidator = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(securityProperties.getConciergeSecret());
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder
                .withSecretKey(new SecretKeySpec(decoded, 0, decoded.length, "AES"))
                .build();
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(jwtValidator);
        return jwtDecoder;
    }
```

Now I know it does not add up. I'm not sure where to use the secret key in token creation, and i'm having trouble creating the decoder. Is there a more proper way for this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a public key for the decoder? You're generating and using a private key with the ES256 algorithm when creating the token. ES256 is a asymmetric algorithm, so you need the corresponding public key to verify the signature. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I basically created my own implementation of JwtDecoder (literally just implemented JwtDecoder into my own class), overrode the `decode` method, and made my own implementation of how to validate the token (e.g. get the claims and check expiry)

Comment: Hey do you mind sharing the implementation that solved this issue?

Comment: @seju basically the same with my sample above, just put it inside the `decode` method of a JwtDecoder implementation. In the decode method, you can just do whatever you want - use a third party issuing authenticator or validate the claims that you would expect is inside the token.